# Sorting XML nodes based on DateTime attribute C#, XPath (refer to an old post)

Tags: c#, xml, sorting

I'm referring to this old post:
[Sorting XML nodes based on DateTime attribute C#, XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344737/sorting-xml-nodes-based-on-datetime-attribute-c-xpath)

I put my question today (it is visible in the bottom) but I'm afraid it won't be visible since the post is old... so I'm asking as new question... 
I tryed a piece of code by Timothy Khouri but I can't manage to make it run, can you help me guys?
Please, read the old post to see the code I'm talking about.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you have (because it won't be exactly the same as his).

Comment: "but I can't manage to make it run" - Please say *exactly* what happens when you try. For example, it sounds like it could be a .NET/C# version issue, but without the message / etc we can't tell.

Comment: I'm using visual c# 2008 express edition, i get that piece of code underlined in red and can't go on running the application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys... my fault...
I was working in an application which was created with 2005 environment of visual c# by origin...
I started a new project from scratch with V. C# 2008 and it worked...
Sorry for the mistake...
Thank for your replies.